# keep screen from dimming down when running certain app?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, settings, screen, screen-brightness

My 2.3.5 Android phone is set up to dim down the brightness after 30 seconds of inactivity, and shut off and lock the screen after another 30 seconds. After that, I need to unlock the screen to regain access to the running app. I would like to be able to keep a certain app with the screen accessible, while keeping the same configuration for any of the other apps. So instead of having a phone-wide system of brightness dimming, I would like to have an app-specific system. Any ideas?

Comment: Settings -> Display -> Screen timeout?

Comment: Just to reiterate, I want this to be different for a specific application than it is for the rest.

Comment: There is a system permission that the app can request that allows it to keep the screen on while the app is running. This is how programs like media players are able to keep the screen on while you're watching a movie. If the app you're running doesn't currently have that facility, you could get in touch with the dev to ask them to implement this.

Answer (score 3):

That's easily possible using [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (I do the same for selected reading apps to *increase* the timeout to 2min, while also having the 30s default for all other apps):

- **Condition:** App (select the apps you want to keep the screen active for)
- **Task:** Display Timeout (configure the timeout interval using the sliders)

Alternatively, in "Task" you could also let *Tasker* switching the *keyguard* off to disable the lock screen.

At least concerning the display timeout adjustment, this might be possible with other automation apps as well, such as Llama -- I'm not sure, as I use *Tasker* I don't use the others. Though *Tasker* might look a bit pricy (~5 EUR) and complicated, after you figured out how to use it you will find it worth every cent. Until then, there's a free trial available on their homepage.

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I am looking for, but ideally for free (and open source).

Comment: The trial is free for 7 days. On day 6 (or whenever your config is stable), export configuration and profiles. On day 7, uninstall the app, reinstall, and import configuration/profiles. So it runs for 7 more days (this hint comes from the dev himself). I know of no other tool as powerful as *Tasker*, but feel free to look around -- might well be you don't need "that much power", so some other app would be enough. Considering the work and effort put into *Tasker*, the fee is nothing more than a friendly pat on the back.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama), which might be able to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app you could use: [Stay Alive! Keep screen awake](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.synetics.stay.alive)

Comment: it prevented the screen going dim while usb is connected, cool thx!